# unity line renderer contant width

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am currently developing a game in unity where planets orbit a sun. i need to draw the circle that shows the path of the orbit. here is the code i have done to draw the circles using LineRenderer

```
        LineRenderer line = moonOrbitTracks[ii].GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        line.SetVertexCount(segments + 1);
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.SetWidth(1, 1);
        line.widthMultiplier = trackWidth;


        float x;
        float z;

        float angle = 20f;

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * 
            (float)childMoons[ii].OrbitRadius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * 
            (float)childMoons[ii].OrbitRadius;

            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, z, 0));

            angle += (360f / segments);
        }
```

when i zoom in in the game. the lines get bigger obviously. but i want them to stay the same width. i tried to do this by doing the following code in the camera class.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f) // forward
    {
        if (MainCamera.orthographicSize > 20)
        {
            MainCamera.orthographicSize = MainCamera.orthographicSize - (MainCamera.orthographicSize * 0.2f);
            Star.trackWidth -= Star.trackWidth * 0.2f;
            Planet.trackWidth -= Planet.trackWidth*0.2f;
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f) // backwards
    {

        MainCamera.orthographicSize = MainCamera.orthographicSize + (MainCamera.orthographicSize*0.2f);
        Star.trackWidth += Star.trackWidth * 0.2f;
        Planet.trackWidth += Planet.trackWidth * 0.2f;
    }
}
```

the problem is that some of the lines do scale with the camera's zoom and some of them dont. but if i move around on the "scene" view the lines will sometimes update. as if it should have changed size but forgot to until it was updated.

i can send you guys the game files so far if necessary. however, I feel like there is a more obvious way of doing this... is there another way to have the lines drawn by the linerenderer to be of constant width regardless of the zoom of the camera

Comment: Are you calling the first block of code in `Update`?  You should run `GetComponent` in `Start` if you are able to do so, and you need to run `line.widthMultiplier = trackWidth;` in `Update`.

Comment: yes, the first block of code is being run in Update()
i used ".AddComponent<LineRenderer>();" in Start()

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the planet and lines?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YcXkXGO
here you will see my point. one of the circles does scale while the rest of them does not. i checked and they all have a width of "8.237" but only one of them is actually showing up with that width

Comment: okay i found a rather inneficient way of fixing it. but it is all i have got at the moment. if i destroy the old lines and completely redraw them then it fixed the problem i have addressed. however simply just changing their widthMultiplier withotu redrawing them was causing me issues

Comment: @arcturus125 Did you ever find a more efficient solution for this issue?